# What is the biggest numerical primitive datatype in C++ (old/new standard)

Tags: c++

I am a bit confused about old/new so that's my question. 
What is the biggest numerical primitive datatype in the old and in the new C++ standard?
(integer and floatingpoint)

regards & many thanks in advance
Oops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 1998 standard, `long int` and `unsigned long int` are the types that are at least as big as any of the standard's other integral types (§3.9.1/2-3). (They may or may not be "the biggest" types. It's possible for `long int` to be the same size as `int`, for instance. For that matter, `char` could be the same size, too.) The floating-point `long double` provides at least as much precision as the other two floating-point types (§3.9.1/8).

In the draft standard for C++0x ([n3092](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf)), the types are `long long int` and `unsigned long long int` (§3.9.1/2-3). The most precise floating-point type remains `long double` (§3.9.1/8).

Implementations may provide bigger types beyond what the standard calls for. Check the documentation for details on that.

Comment: However, C++0x has `<stdint>`, so intmax_t and uintmax_t are the biggest integer types.

Comment: just for the record, the standard does specify minimum sizes, so a `long int` can never be the same size as a char. From memory, an `int` must be at least 16 bits wide, and a `long int` at least 32.

Comment: And in C++0x, even operations such as `sizeof` and things may yield types even bigger than `unsigned long long`, but not so on C++03.

Comment: @jalf: I think they're only bit minimums, so `char` could be the same size as `long` if CHAR_BIT was 32, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

[C and C++ Data Types](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/datatypes.c.php)

[Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx)

[Variables. Data Types.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) *section Fundamental data types*

Answer (score 1):

In C++03, `long [int]` and `unsigned long [int]` have greatest integral range and `long double` has greatest FP precision and range.

In C++0x, `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` have greatest integral range, and may even be bigger than `long long`. For example, it would be reasonable for an implementation to make both `long` and `long long` 64-bit and make `intmax_t` 128-bit.

`intmax_t` is merely being adopted from C99, so if your implementation supports C99, you don't need to require C++0x. Simply include `stdint.h` instead of `cstdint`. Use of "C-style" headers is perfectly safe anyway, although I'm not sure if there's a good way to check for C99 typedefs within C++.

Precisely or conveniently named floating point types were not introduced with C99 or C++0x, so do avoid anything like `float64_t` or `floatmax_t` if you want portability.

Comment: I still think that `intmax_t` should have been named `longest long int`.